# Is this explanation of liberal-conservatism correct?

Tags: conservatism, liberalism

The liberal-conservatism idea is basically:

(1) The socio-economico-political system (which includes a liberal economy and civil rights) we have now happened because it happened (and certainly not because anybody rationally produced it).

(2) It is good (because I like it, not because I have rational arguments for why it is good), so let's not change it.

Is it correct, or is it a straw man?

Quotes:

- Edmund Burke

"Abstract liberty, like other mere abstractions, is not to be found. Liberty inheres in some sensible object; and every nation has formed to itself some favorite point, which by way of eminence becomes the criterion of their happiness." ([Conciliation with America](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Page:Burke%27s_Speech_on_Conciliation_with_America.djvu/72))

- Roger Scruton

"Conservatism is about the love of the place where you are and the attempt to conserve it, what's wrong with that?" ([Oxford Union](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KUbfMQ91Mps&t=1517s))

- Friedrich Hayek

"What I have described as the liberal position shares with conservatism a distrust of reason to the extent that the liberal is very much aware that we do not know all the answers and that he is not sure that the answers he has are certainly the rights ones or even that we can find all the answers. He also does not disdain to seek assistance from whatever non-rational institutions or habits have proved their worth." ([Why I am not a conservative](https://www.cato.org/sites/cato.org/files/articles/hayek-why-i-am-not-conservative.pdf))

Comment: VTC because the question appears to discredit liberal conservatives. (especially alleging that they do not have rational arguments). Asking whether something is a straw man does not offer absolution for presenting the straw man in the first place. A better question might be (for point 1) "How do liberal conservatives view the history of liberalism?" or (point 2) "How do liberal conservatives justify the current liberal order?"

Comment: @xyldke The problem is that (1) and (2) come directly from the statements made by liberal conservatives (Roger Scruton, Edmund Burke, Friedrich Hayek).

Comment: I would like to read these statements. I would *especially* like to read them as part of an answer to a more neutrally worded and open-ended question. :P

Comment: I hate that these liberal conservative questions are immediately closed as soon as they are asked.   Yes Liberal Conservative political scale is unpopular in academia so what.    It's Also the most widely used political scale in existence today.   It was used historically, and is still used today. People should know what the terms mean.  That a Political Board like this one doesn't even entertain these questions is a travesty.   This is a valid question, people should be permitted to respond.

Comment: @xyldke I added some quotes

Comment: @JMS I may have been too facetious, in which case I am sorry but the second part of my comment was actually more important to me. I think the quote by Hayek in particular could lend some credibility in your argument but it is not appropriate to put your argument in the question. If you are interested in exploring liberal conservative throught, you can always ask questions about *their beliefs* but you shouldn't ask about *your thoughts on their beliefs*, which this question does.

Comment: @xyldke  I guess I see this question as more of a hypothetical one and not one relating to modern policies.   I don't take offense to noting inherent strengths and weaknesses of each approach.   Nor does it diminish one to note you really need to use both approaches to have a functioning government that survives over any period of time.

Comment: This strikes me as more of a statement with an "Am I right?" tacked on than an actual question.

Comment: @SamIamsaysReinstateMonica But this question gives all the freedom to state otherwise, and that with an in-depth explanation, argumentation, and justificiation (which I am basically seeking for, asking this question).

Comment: And I don't think it is discrediting political views, because this synthesis comes directly from the statements of the founders of this ideology (which are properly quoting in my question)

Comment: @xyldke Although I express my gratitude to the contributors for having explained quickly, transparently, and rationally their reaction against/toward my question.

Comment: There's nothing here about how liberalism and conservatism is a unitary phenomenon. You just added the two together as I can see from your edits. There should be a discussion of the abstract similarities underlying the two for a coherent 'liberalism-conservatism'

Comment: @user84614 "liberal conservatism" is a years-long political tradition starting from Edmund Burke https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liberal_conservatism#

Comment: @Starckman I would hope that it's years long. I'm not seeing much analysis of it in your answer given that you simply said it's being liberal and conservative at the same time (from your edit history)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Question:**
>
> Are these definitions of liberal or conservative correct?
>
> **Liberal**
>
> (1) The socio-economico-political system (which includes a liberal economy and civil rights) **we have now happened because it happened (and certainly not because anybody rationally produced it).
>
> **Conservative**
>
> (2) It is good (because I like it, not because I have rational arguments for why it is good), so let's not change it.

**Bottom Line Up Front:**

Both Liberal and Conservative are universally naturally occurring.  Both are socio economic.  Liberalism is likely less planned by nature and conservatism arguable better understood and more planned.  Both definitions are fair, though vague, abstract and without context.

Conservative and Liberal are the yin and yang of problem solving.  When faced with a problem one can either find a solution which has worked before, conservativism;  or look for a new solution (liberal).  Even the most ardent believers from the extremes make use of both processes.  I should say naturally occurring with a cavoite.   They occur naturally where people have the freedom to choose a best solution.

**Longer Answer:**
Definitions what does Liberal and conservative mean?   Let's skip over the colloquial good and bad, black and white definitions.

> **Dictionary Definitions>**
>
> **[Conservative](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/conservative_2)** - a person with conservative political views who supports tradition and is often opposed to change.
>
> **[Liberal](https://www.americanprogress.org/article/think-again-the-word-liberal)** -  someone who looks ahead and not behind, someone who welcomes new ideas without rigid reactions.

Why was the Roman senator Cato, and President Reagan both considered conservative yet likely didn't agree on much?  Why were Thomas Paine, and President Franklin D Roosevelt considered liberals?  It's about where they look for solutions.  Left or Liberals when faced with a problem  tend to think of new solutions.  They look forward not backwards.  Right or Conservatives when faced with a problem tend to fall back to solutions which have worked previously.   Well known, better understood solutions.

The net effect is conservative ideas tend to be safer on average.  They are generally understood and thus understood to be an improvement before they're implemented.  The draw back is they are also by definition compromises. There would have to have been some reason why those ideals once practiced were previously abandoned.  Good and bad.

While liberal ideals tend to be inherently more dangerous.  Trying something new is just more prone to fail.  Alternatively for systemic problems, (healthcare crisis, global warming, civil rights in the 1960's) conservatives have no historic solution to look back upon,  they are prone to favor the status quo rather than take a risk.  Most social, scientific progress are inherently liberal ideals, new thinking.  While if you show me any society which functions there are conservative hands at work.

The United States was founded by Lefties.  Washington, Jefferson,  all the founding fathers were Revolutionaries.  Revolutionaries are by definition extreme lefties.
Our Historical examples from above.  Cato was a Senator of Rome and during the Roman revolution and early empire he was strongly in favor of returning to a Republic, that's why he is considered a conservative.  Paine was an age of enlightenment thinker who also favored Republics but is considered liberal because in Paine's time republics were a new solution, the old tried and true solution was Monarchies.  Their really were no republics in Paine's time, not on the scale of France and the U.S as he was advocating.   (ignoring Ragusa, small city state republic in modern day Dubrovnik.)

As a society you really need both.  You need liberals because they give you progress.  You need conservatives because they keep things running.  Business and things like markets work better with stability.  Ideally for a functional society you need both because they are linked.

Successful countries in general are those blessed by moderation.  In the US the most conservative presidents and most liberal ones were mostly moderates.  They possessed both liberal and conservative traits and blended the two approaches, which is to say they were competent (the best ones).

Comment: I like your definition of "liberalism". Then we can distinguish between "collevistic liberals" and "individualist liberals", but still, you made the point

Comment: @Starckman,  In academia this old one dimensional political scale is out of favor as too vague.   Preferred are the multi dimensional political scales that add precision and complexity.  The problem is the more modern political scales are not used outside academia.   Being familiar with the old one dimensional scale  is important because it's so widely used.   People who brand themselves liberal or conservative should understand that competency is not found in either label but in how you mix the two, as all do.  To reason people must be able to recognize and categorize args for themselves.

Comment: Your argumentation evokes me the modern big political parties in Europe and the US, with the left major parties mixing a redistributive free-market capitalism with a great liberalism concerning civil rights; and the right major parties (which ideology is, from what I read, liberal-conservatism); mixing a moderate cultural conservatism with a great free-market capitalism. So the mix of liberalism and conservatism you are talking about, applied to either left or right